# Save html table to Excel - XLS not HTML

Tags: asp.net

I have the following **Code Behind **in aspxnet and it works!!

```
  protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

       
            string NameFile= $"FIT-{hfIdRecalada.Value}.xls";

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={NameFile}");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Output.Write(Request.Form[hfGridHtml.UniqueID]);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
```

but when editing the Excel, it shows web page type "Html"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWCQ0.png)

Thank!!

You know it can be in native excel format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guspG.png)